# ServletContextListener initialized and inmediatly destroyed in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

I have developed a web application in a Tomcat 6 enviroment. This app implements a ServletContextListener like this one:

```
public  class AppListener implements ServletContextListener {
  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog("STLOG." + AppListener.class.getName());

 public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event){
  log.info("MyWebApp is finished.");
 }
 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event){
  log.info("MyWebApp is ready.");
 }
}
```

When MyWebApp runs in Tomcat 6, the logs shows "MyWebApp is ready." when server is started up and "MyWebApp is finished." when it is shuted down.
But the stange thing is that when the app runs in a Tomcat 7 server, I get both messages in the startup.
In any other way I have noticed, the app works the same in boths servers, that is fine.
Anyone could tell my why that differece, and implications if any it may have in my app lifecycle?

Comment: Maybe your Tomcat7 just tests the webapp if it is valid and unloads it until you actually make any requests to it? Check if `contextInitialized()` is called again and `contextDestroyed()` not called if you load it in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `mywebapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` give version="3.0 attribute on Tomcat7 deployment?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0" >

  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.myapp.AppListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

...rest, listeners, filters, servlets...

</web-app>
```